# How to search for specific word using BS4, then get text in same element immediately after that word?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to BeautifulSoup and to Python. I am crawling some pages where sometimes a phone number is given and sometimes it is not. If it's there, I want to scrape it. The HTML is very simple:

```
<div>
    <p>Email: someone@somewhere.com</p>
    <p>Telephone: 1234567890</p>
    <p>Postal code: B3H 2F5</p>

</div>
```

I am checking to see if the phone number is there like this:

```
phoneNumber = soup.find(string='Telephone:')
if phoneNumber:
    phoneNumber = # Some code here to get the actual number 
else:
    phoneNumber = ('None')
print (phoneNumber)
```

There are usually several other p tags in that div, but the same ones aren't always there, so I can't rely on them as reference points. The phone number doesn't always follow the same pattern, either. The best I can do is identify that a phone number is always preceded by 'Telephone:' and is wrapped in a p tag. This seems to be the only surefire way to locate it.

What I don't understand is how to get the actual phone number, that is, anything in the

tag after 'Telephone:'

How do I get the numbers in this element after the word 'Telephone:'?

Comment: If its always ``preceded by :`` you can just do a `str.split(':')[1]` to get the phone number.

Comment: That's why there's `try/except`, otherwise compare based on length

Comment: @sushanth it is in fact always preceded by a `:` but if I do `phoneNumber = str.split(':')[1]` it always returns `None`.

Comment: @MBWD, works fine for me ``for p in soup.find("div").find_all('p'):print(p.text.split(":"))``

Comment: @sushanth I need to assign the variable phoneNumber to those numbers, if they exist on the page, so that it can be included in a JSON dump, rather than just print them out. Also, sometimes the `p` tags are in a different order than what is shown above, hence why I need to search by the word 'Telephone:'.

Comment: @MBWD, you can include the expected output to avoid confusion & further discussion.

Comment: @MBWD then you've to [edit] your question and include full details towards the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some Regex logic you can find directly the `<p>` tag containing the phone number :

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div>
    <p>Email: someone@somewhere.com</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>Postal code: B3H 2F5</p>
    <p>Telephone: 1234567890</p>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

#Find the tag containing "Telephone:"
phone_tag = soup.find('p', text=re.compile('Telephone:'))

if phone_tag:
    phone = phone_tag.text.replace('Telephone:','').strip()
else:
    phone = None
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I was ignorant of a better way to search for this string using `re.compile`. I'll post the answer here in case anyone else is looking for the same thing.

What worked for me is:

```
phoneNumber = soup.find('p', text = re.compile('Telephone:'))
```

This gives me the whole p tag the string appears in, which I did not realize at first, so then I can do:

```
if phoneNumber:
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.get_text().strip().replace('Telephone:', '')
else:
    phoneNumber = ('None')
```